# Browse app folder shared in iTunes file sharing

Tags: titanium, directory, itunes, appcelerator-mobile

In our app, I have predefined folders within the app Documents folder & they're shared through iTunes file sharing. The folders can be viewed by iTunes, however I couldn't browse into the folder. Double click doesn't work. The only option to see the content is to copy the folder out to the Mac. Is there any configuration that is needed to enable browsing into app folders that are shared through iTunes?

Note: App develop using Appcelerator Titanium, tested on iPhone 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't browse the folders. To do so you must save the folder to your computer and use that to browse it. The only real alternative is just to not have folders and have all the files together in the Documents folder.